# SDL flips both surfaces

Tags: c++, sdl

I use SDL for my programs graphics and I have a problem with it in flipping surfaces.When I compile following code:

```
int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
SDL_Surface* scr1 = SDL_SetVideoMode(880 , 600 , 0 , SDL_HWSURFACE |SDL_DOUBLEBUF );
SDL_Surface* scr2 = SDL_SetVideoMode(880 , 600 , 0 , SDL_HWSURFACE |SDL_DOUBLEBUF );

aacircleRGBA(scr1 , 50 , 50 , 30 , 255 , 0 , 0 , 255);

SDL_Flip(scr2);

return 0;
}
```

It shows the circle on the screen.But I flipped only scr2.Why does it show the circle?

Comment: You can't have 2 screens in SDL

Comment: @calccrypto: Well, SDL 1.3 does allow multiple windows, but with `SDL_CreateWindow()`, not `SDL_SetVideoMode()`.

Comment: SDL updated? ooooooohhhhhh. im still using 1.2

Comment: @calccrypto: It’s not officially released, but you can get it from the repo.

Comment: I don't want to have two windows.I just want to draw something on scr1 and something else on scr2.But I want to show only one of them.

Comment: @Arman: In that case, you probably want to use `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()` to create your secondary surface and `SDL_BlitSurface()` to copy its contents to the screen surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call `SDL_SetVideoMode()` a second time, the original screen buffer pointer is, in the *general* case, invalid. You shouldn’t be reusing it, because it doesn’t point to an allocated surface anymore.

In this case, calling `SDL_SetVideoMode()` twice with the same parameters gives `scr2 == scr1`, because there is no need for SDL to reallocate the video surface. Drawing on the surface referred to by `scr1` is thus the same as drawing on that referred to by `scr2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.If I create another SDL_Surface in another scope (for example in a function) with the SDL_SetVideoMode() using the same parameters will the two surfaces be same again?

Comment: @Arman-aegit: Yes, but you shouldn’t rely on it. If you want to get a pointer to the current video surface, use `SDL_GetVideoSurface()`.

Answer (score 2):

> On success. The returned surface is freed by SDL_Quit and must not be freed by the 
>   caller. **This rule also includes consecutive calls to SDL_!SetVideoMode** (i.e. resize or resolution change) because the existing surface will be released automatically. Whatever flags SDL_!SetVideoMode could satisfy are set in the flags member of the returned surface.

-- [SDL_SetVideoMode function](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode) (emphasis mine)

There is only one hardware surface to render to, the one that appears on screen immediately after calling `SDL_SetVideoMode`.  where else would you expect that buffer to draw to?